# Anyone encountered the issue where git will automatically git rm everything sometimes?

Tags: git, github

I have this problem for 2 times... I swear I did not git rm anything.

when I do `git status` I found everything git tracks is staged as DELETED.

Which is very annoying. I am using git version 1.7.1

Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you do anything at all? Also, you should upgrade to 2.3.

Comment: Do you have any hook scripts activated in `.git/hooks`?

Comment: no I don't have the file in .git/hooks

Comment: I would like to upgrade..but I am using a supercomputer that I don't have permission to install..

Comment: Actually they have git 1.8.5. I will use it from now on.

Comment: The only thing I can think I did was that.  I am ssh ing to this remote server which has git, I mapped the remote path(which is controlled by git) to my local drive and use Xcode or sublime to modify the code directly on the remote server.

Comment: Could it be that it has nothing to do with git? If its marked as deleted, I presume that the files do not exist on the filesystem on the server anymore. Perhaps something else is deleting the file and hence git shows its been deleted.

Comment: The files still exist there. I am the only user of this server directory. I still can modify files and git add it....then what I see is that only the files I git added is marked as modified and all other files are marked as deleted

Comment: Did you rename any files with `mv` or in other ways (but not `git mv`)? This leads to each file seen as both new (untracked) and removed in `git status`.